# How do i use javascript to read a text file and display it on my website?

Tags: javascript

This is what i tried now:

```
<script>
function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                alert(allText);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
</script>
<script>
readTextFile("http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test.txt");
</script>
```

But it's not working the page throw like meassage without a message error. Just popup a window since it's not working.

What i want to do on my site is to read the file content line by line an display it on my website.

The does exist on the link: http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test.txt

Comment: Try using a relative path without specifying the domain.

Comment: Doing this on chrome like browsing to it: http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test.txt show me the file content. Now i tried to this in my site:  readTextFile("files/theme/test.txt"); it's not giving error now but also not showing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Is your site same as newsxpressmedia.com? If not it is a cross-domain issue. Browsers do not allow ajax calls to access different domain. More [info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: Yes typing newsxpressmedia.com in chrome lead to my website and typing in chrome newsxpressmedia.com/test.txt lead and show the test.txt content. Or newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test.txt

Comment: I tried your code on Chrome console and it seems to be working. I saw the alert message with the contents of the file test.txt. What exactly you want to do?

Comment: palanik you are right it is working but it's showing the text content like a messageBox in a popup window. I want it to show the content of the text file in a small window that is part of my html page and the user can scroll up down to see all the text. Just like the automatic scrolling text there is now in my site when you enter my site.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a [same origin security issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).   Without some special cross origin permissions from the target domain, the browser won't let you do ajax to a site that's at a different domain than your web page.

See MDN's page on the same-origin policy for details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

See MDN's page on CORS for cross origin permissions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS, but this requires cooperation from the target site.

---

The typical work-arounds are either to have your server work as a proxy so you can request the file from your server and your server gets the file from the actual web site or find a way to use an iframe in your web page.